# What happens when modifying Gemfile.lock directly?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Since the second time of `bundle install` execution, dependencies are loaded from Gemfile.lock as long as Gemfile isn't changed.

But I wonder how detection of changes is made between those two files.

For instance, if I'm adding a new dependency directly into Gemfile.lock without adding it into Gemfile (as opposed to the best practice since Gemfile.lock is auto-generated from Gemfile), would a `bundle install` consider Gemfile as changed ?

Indeed, does `bundle install` process compares the whole Gemfile and Gemfile.lock trees in order to detect changes?

If it is, even if I'm adding a dependency directly to Gemfile.lock, Gemfile would be detected as changed (since different) and would re-erase Gemfile.lock (so losing the added dependency...)

What is the process of `bundle install` since the launch for the second time ?

To be more clear, my question is:

Are changes based only from Gemfile ? That means bundler would keep a Gemfile snapshot of every `bundle install` execution number N and merely compares it to the `bundle install` execution N+1 ?

Or no snapshots are created in bundler memory and bundler makes a comparison with Gemfile.lock each time to detect if Gemfile must be considered as changed.

Comment: just Delete Gemlock file, put your required gems in gem file & run `bundle install`. Thats it. I dont think is good idea to think much about gemlock file. ;)

Comment: @uDaY I agree with you but I'm curious about the process under the hood of bundle install :)

Comment: Have you read [this](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html) and [this](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-install.1.html)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you edit your Gemfile.lock then Rails app would depend on another versions of gems... The integrity of your gem-versioning system would be broken in this case. It's a very-very bad idea to edit Gemfile.lock file directly.

Please, be a good guy and make deals with Gemfile only

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is very old, but I recently had to deal with this so I am giving my own answer. Omniauth was recently updated to version 1.3.2 to patch a security issue. I was tasked with updating Omniauth to this new patched version, however upon checking our Gemfile I realized we did not have that Gem in there. So I said well maybe I can just switch the version on Gemfile.lock from 1.3.1 to 1.3.2. Long story short, that would have worked, but turns out I did not have to do it that way. What I ended up doing was issuing the following command

`bundle update omniauth --patch`

Which resulted in the same change I was going to do manually:

```
-    omniauth (1.3.1)
+    omniauth (1.3.2)
```

That said, if you think you need to make changes to Gemfile.lock there is probably a way to make that change without touching the Gemfile.lock itself. Just do `bundle --help` and you will probably find and option to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks, this helped, was looking for the patched version as well!

Comment: My pleasure @Andrei-NiculaePetre